# How to create dataframe from unformatted text in python?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

Iam currently learning python with data science.

I have patient's information(clinical summary) as pdf.

If I give "patient name" as input I want the name as output.
after splitting those data, I want to analyize those data. for example: I may want to find whether the patient is non smoker, or poor sleeper etc.

i have converted pdf to text but i have no idea how to do the above said things.

kindly help me.

this is what i tried so far

```
str1=""""""
for i in range(0,5):
    str1+=df.getPage(i).extractText()
with open("pdfdata.txt","w",encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(str1)

    with open("pdfdata.txt","r") as pf:
        print(pf.read())

    words=str1.split("\n")
```

Comment: Converted to text, does it mean the text is structured in a column wise manner? Or still in .pdf format? If it has a nice shape can you share the header and first line structure.

Comment: If you open a file for writing then open it again for reading before closing (or flushing) you will get unpredictable results

Comment: how can i share pdf file?

Comment: Just to be sure: You should definitely **NOT** share a pdf file with real patient information.